# What behavior should be expected for async methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Please forgive me if there is already a stack q that covers this, I could not find it.

I am working on a web api in asp.net that incorporates a lot of async tasks. I understand the behavior for most of them except for a particular endpoint. Here is an example of what I'm dealing with:

```
public class Service {
    public async Task ReadMessageAsync()
    {
        var messages = db.Messages.Where(/*some pred*/);

        foreach (var m in messages)
        {
            m.isNew = false
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}


// in api controller
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMessages(bool onlyNew)
{
    var messages = service.GetMessages(onlyNew); // this is defined in service class

    await service.ReadMessageAsync(); // async call to mark new messages as not new

    return Ok(messages);
}
```

Some my question relates to the async call under a few different scenarios:

- Does the async call prevent the calling method from returning until the async finishes due to await?
- Would it be safe to change the return type from `Task` to `void`?
- What happens to an async call when the calling thread is terminated (in the instance the request sends response back to client and closes thread)?

I am pretty familiar with other behaviors for different use cases, but these are unclear. Any light that can be shed on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order:

- Does the async call prevent the calling method from returning until the async finishes due to await?

The async call will not prevent the callee from returning. If you use `await` in the callee, then the callee will yield control back to the scheduler and the remainder of the method will be signed up as a continuation which will run once the `await`ed `Task` has completed (or throws an exception).

- Would it be safe to change the return type from Task to void?

Yes - but you're unable to `await` `void` async methods. This is generally OK for event listeners but I wouldn't recommend it elsewhere.

- What happens to an async call when the calling thread is terminated (in the instance the request sends response back to client and closes thread)?

No clue. Hopefully someone else can answer that. Given that `await/async` signs up the rest of the method as a continuation one would assume that if the thread that invoked the Task is aborted, the continuation would be too. But I am talking out of my arse here.

Comment: so in the instance there are 100 messages to iterate over to set the flag to false, the client could get a response before that loop finishes, correct?

Comment: The source you've provided is kind of a bad example. `db.SaveChanges()` will execute synchronously, and you lose all the advantages of async/await. For all intents and purposes, the code you've given will experience no data corruption due to async/await.

Comment: In the example you've given, the request handler is not going to send a response before the changes you make in `ReadMessageAsync` have been executed, due to the fact you are awaiting `ReadMessageAsync` and that `ReadMessageAsync` does not return until `db.SaveChanges()` has finished executing.

Comment: ok, so if even if I did ```await db.SaveChangesAsync()```, it would still have to wait for the loop then before it could send a response?

Comment: the for loop occurs before the await, so, yes.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I want to send a response and not wait on the flag updating. I guess I'll need to figure out a different way of accomplishing this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You aren't going to avoid that by using `await`.